# '' 'django.core.management' could not be resolved from source Pylance'', but can still run server

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I am starting a Django project and I am using visual studio code. I have created a venv folder, udemy, and a django project folder, mypage, as seen from the [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIPGq.png) picture. In `manage.py`, this code `django.core.management`  has yellow wavy line under it. However, I can still use `py manage.py runserver`, and the server is actually running. What is happening and how do I solve it?

Edit: I know what the problem is, I just need to change the interpreter with   the correct venv.

Comment: It isn't a big issue. It happens all the time to me and it has never interfered with my development. It usually is just a case of vscode not being able to access it. Your code **will work perfectly** if running the code has no error